# Django objects.extra, some_id in manytomany relationship

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a custom model,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...votes = M2M(User)
```

I want to query `MyModel` and get an extra attribute, indicating whether a specific user_id is in votes for each `MyModel` (for instance `request.user.id`).

Example

```
{'id': 1, 'has_voted': True}
```

Could I possibly to that with [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)?

Comment: This question isn't clear. Is it a M2M or FK? And do you mean querying against a specific user ID, or just returning a list of which user IDs have voted?

Comment: Terribly sorry, it's a M2M, wrote type. And yes, querying against a specific user id.